# How to redirect logged in user to homepage using Spring and Ldap

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I am using Spring and Ldap for user authentication , Now I want to redirect the user to homepage when user is already logged in , I tried few solutions that I read through google but no luck. Here is my configuration code ...

Spring-Security.xml

```
   <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        access-denied-page="/denied" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">

        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me"
            token-validity-seconds="864000" token-repository-ref="tokenRepository" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/login"
            access="permitAll" />



        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/member/*"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="user/admin/admin"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/user"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_USERS')" />




        <security:form-login login-page="/login/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login/login?error=true"
            default-target-url="/checking" />

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/login/login" logout-url="/login/logout" />

        <security:custom-filter ref="captchaCaptureFilter"
            before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <!-- <security:custom-filter ref="captchaVerifierFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" 
            /> -->

        <!-- <security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/logout.html">
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />

        </security:session-management>
        <security:session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" /> -->
    </security:http>
```

**My Login Controller**

```
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private User user;

    @Autowired
    SecurityContextAccessor securityContextAccessor;

    @RequestMapping(value = "login/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLogindata(
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            Model model) {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        model.addAttribute("error", error);

        if (securityContextAccessor.isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() && auth.getPrincipal() == null) {
            return "login/login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/member/user";
        }
    }
}
```

auth.getName() always gives me anonymous user even if I am already logged in....

Comment: If you've checked the SecurityContextHolder and it contains an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`, then from Spring Security's perspective you aren't authenticated (provided that request passed through the security filter chain). Check your browser is sending a session cookie which matches the session Id once you've authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your target redirection to the home page, 
after successfully login in to the default-target-url in spring-security.xml, instead of default-target-url="/checking" .

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve in /login/login Controller ? 
If you only want to redirect user, after successfully login to the /member/user , you should write:

```
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
         always-use-default-target='true' 
         default-target-url="/member/user"
         authentication-failure-url="/login/login?error=true"
         />
```

And login Controller should look like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model) {
return "login";
}
```

If your authentication provider is OK and correct , Spring security will redirect you automatically to the /member/user after successfully login.

Comment: My question is not to redirect user after successful login, but suppose I got successful login than click on login link I should not be asked to login again rather I should redirect to /member/login

Comment: I would recommend to hide Login link, after successfully login. Something like this:                                             <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

 <sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_DEFAULT,ROLE_ADMIN">
 <a id="login-link" href="#">Login</a> </sec:authorize>